# Set a fixed height without width changing

Tags: html, css

I want to make an image stay at a certain height, but I also want it to stay at the width of the user's screen.

Here's the image's CSS:

```
#cafe {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}
```

Here's the output:
[image]

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: If you have a fixed height, and you want the image to be the width of the browser, then the image's aspect ratio will skew unless that fixed height and the browser width are also whatever the aspect ratio is - which is quite unlikely. Are you OK with that? Seems like something you'd want to avoid.

Comment: You have two options with a set height; **1)** allow the image to be stretched horizontally if the full width of image must be view-able, **2)** allow portions of the image to be hidden if you don't want the image to be stretched horizontally. [Some examples](https://jsfiddle.net/gzwoer80/) using `background-size`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
#cafe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

here the 'vh' means VIEWPORT HEIGHT which automatically takes the user's screen height.

Comment: That works but now I kinda want the height to be less and when I change the vh to something like 65 the image looks stretched.

Comment: @JordanBaron having a set height plus a variable width will always stretch the image. That is, unless you're willing to allow portions of the image to be hidden so the image's aspect ratio can be maintained.

Comment: Yes I am willing to do that, but how?

Comment: @JordanBaron see my examples in my comment to your post.